# Login validation and how to make sure an email that is entered is in a database

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit, android-jetpack-compose

So I was looking up ways to validate a field when the user was inputting information. I found a way where I can actually validate the email, but it wasn't enough because there was still ways to bypass it.

```
@Composable
fun LoginField(
    loading: Boolean = false,
    onDone: (String) -> Unit = {email ->}
){
    val email = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    val valid = remember(email.value){
        email.value.trim().isNotEmpty()
    }
    val context = LocalContext.current

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        EmailInput(
            emailState = email,
        )

        SubmitButton(
            textId = "Login",
            loading = loading,
            validInputs = valid
        ){
            //The change needs to happen below
            if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email.value).matches()){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Please enter a valid email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            else{
                onDone(email.value.trim())
                keyboardController?.hide()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since the database stores emails that is authorize to use the app, How can I compare the user input to those entries in the database, to validate the email input. Any suggestion is welcomed. Thanks.

P.S. Just want to check if the email is inside the database.

Comment: I'm confused, do you want to just check whether the given email adress is in the database or is it even a valid email in the first place?

Comment: I want to check if the email is in the database.